# jQuery Iframe Link Fade In - FadeOut

Tags: jquery, iframe, navigation, hyperlink, fade

The problem I am experiencing is in the fiddle. When I click on the About link the iframe fades in with the text (the text is in an about-me.html file which I do not know how to include in the fiddle and its just plain h1 header text with a paragraph below it), but when I click the Portfolio link the text from the portfolio-me.html just appears in the iframe and it doesn't fade in. I would want the iframe to fade in with the text when I click the About link, and when I click the Portfolio link I want the iframe (and the About text in the about-me.html) to fade out and fade in the iframe with the portfolio-me.html and so on for the other links. Would you please solve this problem for me, explain it, and include other solutions for this problem and explain them? I am a begginer in jquery and I tried to solve it by adding data and unloading stuff but it didn't work.
Thank you in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".about").on("click",function(){
        $('iframe').load(function() {
            $('#iframeContainer').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });

    $(".about").on("click",".portfolio",function(){
        $("iframe").load(function(){
            $("iframeContainer").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VA6Hr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you. Notice I've changed bits of the HTML and CSS to improve the code.

HTML:

```
<ul class="bmenu">
    <li><a href="about-me.html" class="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio-me.html" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog-me.html" class="blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact-me.html" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="iframeContainer">
  <iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#iframeContainer { display: none; }

iframe {
    margin-left:100px;
    width:300px; height:300px;
    border: 1px solid #000; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.bmenu a').click(function(){
        var iframeSrc = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#iframeContainer').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $('#iframeContainer iframe').attr('src',iframeSrc);
            $('#iframeContainer').fadeIn(1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VA6Hr/1/

This code uses the link hrefs as the src for the iframe.